# Exit Popup Redirect but only execute on exit not on clicking any other html redirect button on page

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

l am using this code

```
var exitPop = false;
var nonFire = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(!exitPop){
        exitPop=true;
        return 'Wait! YOU ARE TODAYS WINNER!';
    }
};

setInterval(function(){
    if(exitPop && !nonFire){
        nonFire = true;
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
}, 200);
```

but its also execute on clicking any html redirect button on page.. i want it execute only if someone close browser and it should support all browsers.

i need to add this at only one link in my site how can id do?  i mean i am using this code for redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.remove',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });   
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
//]]>
</script>
```

so i want exit function do not execute for this.. so how do integrate this

Comment: When indicating something is code on SO, indent with four spaces. You use `> ` for blockquotes.

Comment: Personal opinion: Pages that add listeners to `beforeunload` and beg you to stay because `YOU ARE THE WINNNER!` do as much for the web as animated gif under construction signs.

Comment: No good comes from forcing users to stay on your site, if its worth someones time and keeps them engaged then there stay and there is no need for `Wait! YOU ARE TODAYS WINNER!` antics...

Comment: This is today's lesson on how to drive users away from you're website! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but you should be able to attach a 'click' event to every link on the page, which should set a global variable such as

```
linkClicked = true;
```

You can then check that variable in the unload event

```
if (!linkClicked) // variable is false so they must not have clicked on a link
{
    // Some annoying message here
}
```

Disclaimer: this is pretty much pseudo code, it's not a copy+paste solution.

Comment: i need to add this at only one link in my site how can id do?  i mean i am using this code for redirect

Answer (score 0):

`window.onbeforeunload` does not distinguish between links, back/forward buttons, exit buttons or anything else.  If fires when you leave the page, regardless of how you leave the page.